# Paramiko raises "SFTPError: Garbage packet received"

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

The following code:

```
    t = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
    t.connect(username=username, password=password)
    sftp = t.open_sftp_client()
```

Raises this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\elqstux\workspace\WxPython\FetcchFile.py", line 41, in <module>
sftp = t.open_sftp_client()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 845, in        open_sftp_client
return SFTPClient.from_transport(self)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 106, in from_transport
return cls(chan)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 87, in __init__
server_version = self._send_version()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp.py", line 108, in _send_version
t, data = self._read_packet()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp.py", line 179, in _read_packet
raise SFTPError('Garbage packet received')
SFTPError: Garbage packet received
```

My host's ip is `147.214.16.150`, I use use this command to test in console:

```
esekilvxen245 [11:03am] [/home/elqstux] -> sftp 147.214.16.150
Connecting to 147.214.16.150...

These computer resources, specifically Internet access and E-mail, are
provided for authorized users only. For legal, security and cost
reasons, utilization and access of resources are monitored and recorded
in log files. All information (whether business or personal) that is
created, received, downloaded, stored, sent or otherwise processed can
be accessed, reviewed, copied, recorded or deleted by Ericsson, in
accordance with approved internal procedures, at any time if deemed
necessary or appropriate, and without advance notice. Any evidence of
unauthorized access or misuse of Ericsson resources may result in
disciplinary actions, including termination of employment or assignment,
and could subject a user to criminal prosecution. Your use of Ericsson's
computer resources constitutes your consent to Ericsson's Policies and
Directives, including the provisions stated above.

IF YOU ARE NOT AN AUTHORIZED USER, PLEASE EXIT IMMEDIATELY

Enter Windows Password: 
Received message too long 1131770482
```

Comment: Are you connecting to an actual SFTP-capable host? Have you tried connecting to it using the `sftp` command-line tool?

Comment: @MartijnPieters  i test it in command-line, the output is `Received message too long 1131770482`.

Comment: Then you need to diagnose *that* part; this is not a Python problem. Your target server is misbehaving.

Comment: @MartijnPieters can you tell how ignore the output?

Comment: You cannot tell Python to ignore that exception because it is *fatal*. The connection cannot be established.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't want to ignore the exception, i just want to establish  it successfully. From the output of command `sftp`, you can see a lot of words, that is the reason.

Comment: Your server is also sending you messages that are too long; that is breaking the connection.

Comment: so i want to ignore the message sended by server.

Comment: I doubt it is the welcome message that is causing the problem. That message is way shorter than the `Received message too long 1131770482`  error implies.

Comment: do you know how to ignore the welcome message.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem, and found that it was due to output from a program 'gvm'.
I fixed it by changing my .bashrc file:

```
#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR GVM TO WORK!!!
#[[ -s "/home/micron/.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh" ]] && source "/home/micron/.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh" <== commented this out.
```

Comment: That's correct, anything that writes to _stdout_ on login will mess up the ftp protocol.